# use and or in two cssSelector

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am using selenium webdriver and i have a scenario like where i have to find out some elements. for this, i use :

```
 driver.findElements(By.cssselector("mycsss"))
```

again, i have to use this to find another some elements. Now my question is,

```
is there any way to find both these elements using there css 
path only in one methods like below:

driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("first element csspath" and "second element csspaht"))
```

pls help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use like below:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("first css path , second css path"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try simply using `,` in between the 2 paths.

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(css_path_1 + ", " css_path_2))
```